# ¿Se puede crear funciones que retornen tablas en MySQL Worckbench? De ser así, ¿Cual sería una correcta sintaxis para su creación?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Por favor alguien si me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: Las funciones, por definición, únicamente pueden devolver el tipo de dato que indicas en su `RETURNS`

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por *retornar tablas*? ¿Te refieres a retornar los nombres de las tablas, los contenidos de las tablas...? Sea como sea, ¿qué has investigado y qué has intentado? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

No es posible, `MySql` no tiene esta característica como la tiene `SQL Server`

Según la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-loadable.html), los retornos permitidos son:

- STRING
- INTEGER
- REAL
- DECIMAL